# Proper locking for reliable insertion (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, t-sql, transactions

When receiving so called IPN message from PayPal, I need to update a row in my database.

The issue is that I need perfect reliability.

Currently I use InnoDB. I am afraid that the transaction may fail due a race condition.

Should I use `LOCK TABLES`? Any other reliable solution?

Should I check for a failure and repeat the transaction several (how many?) times?

Comment: Can you automatically notify PayPal that the process failed? Then you could use transactions. If something fails nothing happens and PayPal need to send you the message later.

Comment: @Eragonio: The trouble is that verification of a PayPal notification is done wrong: It does verification and notification of the PayPal's server in one step. (The right way would be first verify PayPal's notification, then update the DB and only then to notify PayPal. But it cannot be done dies silly way PayPal does.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably make a distributed process (like adding a row locally and notifying the server remotely) *perfectly* reliable, no matter the order. This is a lot like the [Two General's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem): there is no single event which can denote the successful completion of the transaction on both sides simultaneously, as any message might get lost along the way.

I'm not sure I understand your issue correctly, but perhaps the following would work: Write a line to some table noting the fact that you *are going* to verify a given message. Then do the verification, and afterwards write a line to the database about the *result* of that verification. In the unlikely but important scenario that something broke in between, you will have an intent line with no matching result line. You can then detect such situations and recover from them manually.

On your local database, you'd have single row updates, which you may execute in their own transaction, probably even with autocommit turned on. You have to make sure that the first write is actually committed to disk (and preferrably a binary log on some other disk as well) before you start talking to the PayPal server, but I see no need for locking or similar. You migt want to retry failed transactions, I'd say up to three times, but the important thing is that in the end you can have admin intervention to fix anything your code can't handle.

Comment: If a PayPal payment notification is not responded with a confirmation, this notification may be repeated. It make possible what you've marked impossible in your answer

Comment: I mean that the possibility to repeat it a big number of times makes it almost reliable.

Comment: @porton: Then I don't see how the combination of verification and notification you mention in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767618/proper-locking-for-reliable-insertion-mysql#comment17257143_12767618) can be a problem.

Comment: For reliability updating the DB should be between verification and notification that we processed it. When verification and notification are one step we can't insert DB update in the middle, as it should be